# dataTable - Search and Number of entries incorrect

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm displaying my data from `database` using `dataTable`. But the `Number of Entries` and `Search` box is not working properly. `Entries` are not match on the number of `rows` that I have and `Search` box is not working. What seems to be the problem?

Here is my table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-gatepass">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Consignee
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        Address
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       Broker Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       Carrying Aircraft
                    </th>
<th>
                        Registration No.
                    </th>

<th>
                        Date of Arrival 
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Exportation   
                    </th>
                    <th >
                        PKG
                    </th>
                     <th >
                        Gross Weight
                    </th>
                     <th >
                        AWB/MAWB No.
                    </th>
                     <th >
                        HAWB No.
                    </th>
                     <th >
                        Action
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($results as $key){?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $key['consignee'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $key['address1'].' '.$key['address2'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $key['broker'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $key['carrying_aircraft'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $key['reg_no'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $key['date_arrival'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $key['air_exportation'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $key['pkg'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $key['gross_weight'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $key['awb_mawb'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $key['hawb'];?></td>
                    <td>

<a  target="_blank" href="<?php echo site_url('gatepass/gatepass_print?id='.$key['gatepass_ID']);?>"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs blue tooltips " title="print" data-container="body" data-placement="top" data-html="true"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></button></a>
                    </td>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </tr>




            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And in my external js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#dataTables-gatepass').dataTable();

});
```

Comment: you have an extra set of tbody tags

Comment: @Bindrid I missed that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dataTables-gatepass').dataTable();



// #myInput is a <input type="text"> element

$('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table.search( this.value ).draw();
});
```

And for more information use this link https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()